Why Doesn't EM_SETCUEBANNER Work with TEdit?
In Delphi FireMonkey, I'm unable to display a TextPrompt in a TEdit control (with ControlType set to Platform) on Windows. The expected placeholder text doesn't appear, even though the code located in FMX.Edit.Win.pas : SendTextMessage(Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, WPARAM(1), Model.TextPrompt) return 0 (false?) and GetLastError returns 0 (no error?)! This approach works in VCL, but not in my FireMonkey application. Why might this be, and how can I fix it?
When i run mt.exe to extract the manifest ("c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\mt.exe" -inputresource:c:\myapp\myapp.exe;#1 -out:c:\myapp\myapp.manifest) this is what I get:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/pm</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" processorArchitecture="*"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
        <!--The ID below indicates app support for Windows Vista -->
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"></supportedOS> 
        <!--The ID below indicates app support for Windows 7 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"></supportedOS>
        <!--The ID below indicates app support for Windows 8 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"></supportedOS>
        <!--The ID below indicates app support for Windows 8.1 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"></supportedOS>
        <!--The ID below indicates app support for Windows 10 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"></supportedOS>         
    </application> 
</compatibility>
</assembly>

As far as I understand ComCtrl32 v6 is activated ? (because this is necessary for EM_SETCUEBANNER to work)

I'm wondering why you want to display a prompt that way, when the TEdit has a TextPrompt property.

Does your FireMonkey project have an app manifest that enables ComCtrl32 v6 at the platform level for Visual Styles? EM_SETCUEBANNER won't work without that. VCL projects have a setting to enable such a manifest. Not sure about FireMonkey projects

@PhilipJ.Rayment it's because the TextPrompt property of the TEdit is not working (when controltype=plateform) and I investigate why. look like it's because the EM_SETCUEBANNER is not working

@RemyLebeau I was thinking the same but it's look like ComCtrl32 v6 is activated. You can try yourself, it's very simple launch a new blank firemonkey app with a Tedit that have controltype=plateform and textprompt="ohohoh" you will see textprompt is not showed :(

@zeus which version of Delphi are you using?

@RemyLebeau Athens, but I try on Alexandria or Sydney same problem :(
